# Tree View Hierarchical DataTemplate Binding - MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, treeview

Here I'm trying to bind 'Solution' List to TreeView. Each 'Solution' has 'File' List and 'Solution Name'. I want to use Hierarchical DataTemplate to do this. In Debug mode I checked that 'Solution' List and 'File' list are successfully set. But in my view there is nothing shown. 
In addition, in my view class when I try to set Data Type of the Hierarchical DataTemplate, it says "SolutionExplorerModel" does not exist int the namespace even though it does.

### ViewModel

```
public class SolutionExplorerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<SolutionExplorerModel> _solutions = new List<SolutionExplorerModel>();
        public List<SolutionExplorerModel> Solutions
        {
            get { return _solutions; }
            set
            {
                _solutions = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Solutions");
            }
        }

        public SolutionExplorerViewModel()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<OpenFileDialog>(this, OnItemReceived);
        }

        private void OnItemReceived(OpenFileDialog openFile)
        {
            var solutionName = openFile.SafeFileName.Replace(".psim", "");
            var files = new List<FileModel>();
            var solutionPath = openFile.FileName.Replace(openFile.SafeFileName, "");
            foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(solutionPath, "*.xml"))
            {
                files.Add(new FileModel(file));
            }
            var newSolution = new SolutionExplorerModel
            {
                SolutionName = solutionName,
                Files = files
            };
            _solutions.Add(newSolution);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyThatChanged)
        {
            //checking if event is not null than raise event and pass
            //in propperty name that has changed
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyThatChanged));
        }
    }
```

### SolutionExplorerModel

```
public class SolutionExplorerModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _solutionName;
        public string SolutionName
        {
            get { return _solutionName; }
            set
            {
                _solutionName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SolutionName");
            }
        }

        private List<FileModel> _files;
        public List<FileModel> Files
        {
            get { return _files; }
            set
            {
                _files = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Files");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyThatChanged)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyThatChanged));
        }
    }
```

### FileModel

```
public class FileModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _safeName;
    public string SafeName
    {
        get { return _safeName; }
        set
        {
            _safeName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SafeName");
        }
    }

    private string _path;
    public string Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set
        {
            _path = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Path");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyThatChanged)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyThatChanged));
    }

    public FileModel(string path)
    {
        this.Path = path;
        this.SafeName = path.Split('\\').LastOrDefault();
    }
}
```

### View

```
 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Solutions}" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource mainViewModelLocater}, Path=SolutionExplorerViewModel}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:SolutionExplorerModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SolutionName}"></TextBlock>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work provided that the `SolutionExplorerViewModel` property of your `mainViewModelLocater` actually returns a populated `SolutionExplorerViewModel`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Solutions}" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource mainViewModelLocater}, Path=SolutionExplorerViewModel}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:SolutionExplorerModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SolutionName}"></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type model:FileModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SafeName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Try to set the `DataContext` explicitly and make sure that you populate the `Solutions` collection:

```
treeView.DataContext = new SolutionExplorerViewModel();
```

Comment: I tried this and I checked `DataContext` after I updated `Solutions`. The data in `DataContext` is correct. But still there is nothing shown in TreeView. I think the problem is in view class because it still says the name `SolutionExplorerModel` does not exist in the namespace

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: Yes it does compile.

Comment: But the view remains just blank at runtime? Then there is something wrong with your data binding or your data.